# Notify developer , If they are not pushing code to gitlab daily

Tags: gitlab

Currently I am working in a project in which we are using Gitlab for repository management. I am the owner of project so I want to automate the code checkin validation on daily basis . my question is , Is there any option so that, I can configure the daily check(whether developer pushed there code or not) and send the notification to developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no build in functionality for this.**

As this is a reasonable feature you should follow the feature request workflow of Gitlab and open an issue for that. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce 
But keep in mind that such feature will be probably only available for the EE version.

As alternative you can use the API of Gitlab to extract the commits of a project.  https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/commits.html

Then process the date diffs using a e.g. python script and send an email or post on a Mattermost channel using their API. https://api.mattermost.com/